# POST method in RESTful API works on HTTPie but not on Android/Postman

Tags: python, flask, postman, flask-restful

I wrote the POST method in RESTful API of Flask and successfully added data to the server using HTTPie, a command line HTTP client. But when I tried it on Android there was an error.
Here is the code of the client:

```py
@app.route('/factories', methods=['POST'])
def create_factory():
    if not request.json or not 'fac_name' in request.json:
        abort(404)
    factory = {
        'id': factories[-1]['id'] + 1,
        'fac_name': request.json['fac_name'],
        'lat': request.json['lat'],
        'lng': request.json['lng']
    }

    factories.append(factory)
    return jsonify({'factory': factory}), 201
```

The HTTPie result is like this:
[image]

The error of Flask:

192.168.0.101 - - [13/May/2019 03:37:44] "POST /factories HTTP/1.1" 500 -
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\Users\Steve\PycharmProjects\test\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2309, in **call**
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)

File "C:\Users\Steve\PycharmProjects\test\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2295, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)

File "C:\Users\Steve\PycharmProjects\test\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1741, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)

File "C:\Users\Steve\PycharmProjects\test\venv\lib\site-packages\flask_compat.py", line 35, in reraise
    raise value

File "C:\Users\Steve\PycharmProjects\test\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2292, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()

File "C:\Users\Steve\PycharmProjects\test\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1815, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)

File "C:\Users\Steve\PycharmProjects\test\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1718, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)

File "C:\Users\Steve\PycharmProjects\test\venv\lib\site-packages\flask_compat.py", line 35, in reraise
    raise value

File "C:\Users\Steve\PycharmProjects\test\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1813, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()

File "C:\Users\Steve\PycharmProjects\test\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1799, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functionsrule.endpoint

File "C:\Users\Steve\PycharmProjects\test\venv\hello.py", line 124, in create_factory

```
'fac_name': request.json['fac_name'],
```

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

UPDATE:
I changed the `if not` line into `if not request.json: abort(401)` and now it is 401 error. And I also tried using Postman and it was the same type of error, so I think this has nothing to do with Android codes and i deleted the Android code from here.

Here's the Postman result:
[image]

Comment: use `request.get_json` instead of `request.json`

Comment: Given the preceding `if not request.json`, I don't see how this error is possible.

Comment: I changed the `if not` line into `if not request.json: abort(401)` and now it is 401 error.

Answer (score 1):

You are expecting a JSON request

```
if not request.json or not 'fac_name' in request.json:
```

But you are sending form-data.

Please check the Radio-Button "raw" and set the content Type to "application/json"
[image: postman]

Then you have to add a valid json in your request body.

Comment: The content type is correct and the request body is `{
    "fac_name": "test",
    "lat":30,
    "lng":110
}`. Still doesn't work.

Comment: maybe didn't help you, but it helped me. I was sending fom-data.

Answer (score 0):

The error is helpful.

```
File "C:\Users\Steve\PycharmProjects\test\venv\hello.py", line 124, in create_factory

'fac_name': request.json['fac_name'],

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

> object is not subscriptable

This means you are trying `['keyword']` on an object that does not support it, namely a `NoneType`.

From which you can deduce `request.json` is `NoneType`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```py
if not request.json or not 'fac_name' in request.json:
        abort(404)
    factory = {
        'id': factories[-1]['id'] + 1,
        'fac_name': request.json['fac_name'],
        'lat': request.json['lat'],
        'lng': request.json['lng']
    }
```

I used

```py
    data=request.data
    j_data = json.loads(data)

    factory = {
        'id': factories[-1]['id'] + 1,
        'fac_name': j_data['fac_name'],
        'lat': j_data['lat'],
        'lng': j_data['lng']
    }
```

And it works. However I have no idea why.